# In Dart, what is the difference between using 'new' keyword and directly calling constructor?

Tags: dart, flutter

I see I am allowed to use

```
argument: MyClassName(a,b)
```

as well as

```
argument: new MyClassName(a,b)
```

I wanted to understand is `new` optional in Dart? Or these two return totally different things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Dart 2.0 strong mode [new and const are optional](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/optional-new-const.md) so both are the same.